# Why DataGridView in C# at compile time (design time) does not show the first empty row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In VS 2013 I added  DataGridView to my Winform.  When I show it in the design time (before I run my code) why does it only show the header columns and not an extra row.

I am looking at some existing C# code, and there is a datagridview within a Winform and when I display that Winform, the dataGridview displays both the Header columns and one empty row.

Comment: I got my answer. I had to set the UserAllowedToAddRows to True in Properties.

Comment: To whoever gave a -1 to this question, I would like to remind  them that I have done research for few days and within 10 minutes after  I posted the question, the light bulb went on. I left the question in there hoping that it would help someone else not waste 3 days worth of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely seeing the blank row that allows users to add a new record.

One of the DataGridView's has the [AllowUserToAddRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows(v=vs.110).aspx) property set to True, which shows the extra blank row. The other one has it set to False, which does not display the extra row.

Here's the difference... the first DataGridView has AllowUserToAddRows enabled; the second disabled:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the AllowUserToAddRows in the Properties to true.

Comment: Why do you need to add your own answer when it is a subset of the answer which is already [provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27361449/2530848) ? You're more than welcome to add your own answer if that provides more information. In this case it isn't.

Comment: @Sriram, thank  you for your post. After I posted my question while still looking for an answer I found it and when I posted my answer I had not seen the other answer.  You probably did not see my comment that I will mark Grant Whinney's answer as the answer as a professional courtesy.  Thanks again for your comment.

Comment: I just saw that. No offense, I didn't mean to discourage you, so please don't be offended. Thanks.